# Convert an element of a list type object in element's type

Tags: c#, list, object, types

I have a `List<Object>` with 3 elements. List's elements type can be `mat1` `mat2` `mat3` randomly defined.

In other part of my code I've to instance object which accept only types `mat1` `mat2` `mat3` but if I use the List's obj, IDE says

> cannot Convert from 'object' to 'mat1'

Example

```
public List<Object> MatList = new List<Object>();
```

MatList contains :

- `mat1` [type `SectionBuilder.AcciaioCarpenteria`]
- `mat2` [type `SectionBuilder.AcciaioArmatura`]
- `mat3` [type `SectionBuilder.Calcestruzzo`]

Somewhere in my code I have to instantiate the object `Fiber`:

```
Fibre.Add(new Fiber( yg,zg,A,  MatList[Index] ));
```

Comment: There's no question here

Comment: Can you be more clear on the requirement. Any sample code that you have tried.

Comment: We need the code. And code of `mat1 mat2 mat3`.

Comment: Fiber Is a type defined by me. I've to convert The elment of the list (Object) to the type of the element (which can be SectionBuilder.AcciaioCarpenteria SectionBuilder.AcciaioArmatura SectionBuilder.Calcestruzzo).

Comment: Sounds like you are only looking for how to cast? `(mat1)MatList[Index]`  (or `(SectionBuilder.AcciaioCarpenteria)MatList[Index]` ) should do the trick, but if possible, using a base class for all the `mat` classes would be preferable.

Comment: Thank you @Me.Name , It works ! i would apologize to all but I'm a newbie on stack overflow

Comment: @AlbertoCompagnone - You probably want `Fibre.Add(new Fiber(yg, zg, A, MatList.OfType<SectionBuilder.AcciaioCarpenteria>().First()));`

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure I understand what you want to do, but maybe you could use

```
MatList.OfType<"the requested type">().Where("type your query").ToList();
```

Comment: Please don't link to external sites unless the link supports content that you've already put in your answer.